# Adding new instructions to the processor lx106

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, esp8266, xtensa

In the xtensa documentation there is a paragraph saying that it is possible to 'burn' new instructions in the processor itself using a sort of C language.
How to create new instruction in an assembly source program or how to link this new instruction to an assembly source. 
For example there is no push instruction and i want to create one.
Please note that i am not asking about how to do a push in a stack which i already know.

Comment: You can't add instructions to an existing ESP8266 chip, if that was what you're hoping. You can "burn" your own custom Xtensa CPU to an FPGA, but this is normally only done for prototyping. In any case what you're asking is way too broad to be answered here. You'll have to read Cadence's documentation.

Comment: Not uncommon for IP like this to have different options as well as adding your own stuff to the code.  But that is pre-silicon not after.

Comment: OK thank you. So it's too late.